# Joint distribution of mid p-value and p-value

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

I have a question about the joint distribution of the mid p-value and p-value.

We know that, for right tailed test with discrete test statistic $X$ with distribution $F$, the p-value is defined as $P=Pr(X \geq  observed~X)$ and the mid p-value is defined as $mid~P=Pr(X \gt observed~X)+\frac{1}{2}*P(X=Observed)$.

I would like to find out $Pr(P_{mid} \leq t~and~P \gt t)$ for some $t \in (0,1)$.  Here $P$ is the p-value and $P_{mid}$ is the mid p-value.

Comment: What test do you have in mind?

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I am hoping to get a general solution for any discrete distribution F.

Comment: The answer depends strongly on the test statistic, not just the distribution: that's why you need to tell us what test you're using.

Comment: Ok.  We can focus on the Fisher's exact test. Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone have any thought on it, please? Thanks

Comment: Simple translation of the question: "I would like to find out values of the [hypergeometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test#Example)."

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that the distribution of $P_{\rm mid}$ more closely approximates a uniform distribution than that of $P$.

$P$ is obviously always slightly larger than $P_{\rm mid}$.
If $X=x$, then the difference between the two p-values is
$$P-P_{\rm mid}=P(X=x)/2$$
On average this is
$$E(P-P_{\rm mid})=\frac12 \sum_x P(X=x)^2.$$
In general, if $X$ can take on many possible distinct values, so that $\max_x P(X=x)$ becomes small, then $E(P-P_{\rm mid})$ will also be small.

If $P(X=x)$ is a decreasing function of $x$, as it usually is for $x$ sufficiently large, then $P-P_{\rm mid}$ will also decrease with $x$.